# A Boolean function that is not constant on affine subspaces of large enough dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, coding-theory

I'm interested in an explicit Boolean function $f \colon \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ with the following property: if $f$ is constant on some affine subspace of $\{0,1\}^n$, then the dimension of this subspace is $o(n)$.

It is not difficult to show that a symmetric function does not satisfy this property
by considering a subspace $A=\{x \in \{0,1\}^n \mid x_1 \oplus x_2=1, x_3 \oplus x_4=1, \dots, x_{n-1} \oplus x_n=1\}$. Any $x \in A$ has exactly $n/2$ $1$'s and hence $f$ is constant on the subspace $A$ of dimension $n/2$.

Cross-post: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/a-boolean-function-that-is-not-constant-on-affine-subspaces-of-large-enough-dimen

Comment: I don't understand. If $f$ is the identity, $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, then $f$ isn't constant on any set of more than 1 element. Have you got the codomain wrong?

Comment: From your use of $o(n)$ notation, it seems like you are asking for an explicit family of functions $f_n$ for infinitely many integers $n$.  Is it standard to call it one function?

Comment: Maybe the target is supposed to be {0,1}.

Comment: Ooops, I'm sorry, the range is {0,1}, of course. Fixed. 

Yes, as far as I know, it is standard to say function instead of an infinite sequence of functions, one for each n. It is usually done in circuit complexity, for example.

Comment: Just to make the obvious observation, a random function has this property. The probability of a random function being constant is `$2*2^{-2^d}$`, and the number of $d$-dimensional subspaces is `$\approx 2^{d(n-d)}$`, so the expected number of constant subspaces is less then $1$ as soon as $d$ is large enough that $2^d > d(n-d)$. (continued)

Comment: I can partially derandomize this and show that a random cubic has the desired property. (Details if wanted.) But I can't figure out how to do better than that.

Comment: Cross posted on [cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/a-boolean-function-that-is-not-constant-on-affine-subspaces-of-large-enough-dimen)

Comment: David, and what is a random cubic?..

One can show that such a function exists by the following argument. Assume that any function is constant on some affine subspace of dimension, say, $5\log n$. Then we can describe any function by less than $2^n$ bits as follows. The corresponding affine subspace is defined by $Ax=b$ for some $A$ and $b$. So, we first use about $n^2$ bits to write down this matrix and this vector and then write down the values of our function on all other $2^n-n^5$ points.

Comment: Are these functions related to so-called "bent functions"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_function

Comment: Hm, it looks similar, but it is different from bent functions, as far as I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misreading it, the paper [Affine dispersers from subspace polynomials](http://web.mit.edu/swastik/www/affine-disperser.pdf) by Ben-Sasson and Kopparty gives an explicit construction which is nonconstant on any affine subspace of dimension less than $6 n^{4/5}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explicit affine extractor construction by Bourgain (GAFA 2007). It is almost unbiased on any linear dimension affine subspace of $\{0,1\} ^n$